# Magnum CI with private github repository

Tags: github, continuous-integration

I am using Magnum CI with a private github repository.

I have the web hook set up for the Magnum CI, the pushes launch a build.

The build is getting an error when pulling the code down from github. I get the error

`remote: Invalid username or password.`

I have the Magnum CI rsa key in the branch settings.

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that Magnum CI requires the SSH of your github. I was using the HTTPS address.

Comment: Could you explain more about your fix? 

I have the same problem. I have added Deploy Key to github repo, but after several build It has status "never used".

Comment: So when you are linking your github to magnum you put in the URL to your git. If you go to your git main page there's a box where you can copy this URL. Click SSH instead of HTTPS and paste the SSH into your repository address for magnum. Magnum is expecting an ssh address.